# std::priority_queue: Custom ordering without defining comparator class

Tags: c++, boost, stl, bind, priority-queue

I want to have a priority queue with custom ordering, but lazy as I am, I don't want to define a comparator class implementing operator().

I really would like something like this to compile:

```
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, 
    boost::bind(some_function, _1, _2, obj1, obj2)> queue;
```

where some_function is a bool returning function taking four arguments, the first and second being ints of the queue, and the two last ones some objects needed for calculating the ordering (const references).

> (error: ‘boost::bind’ cannot appear in a constant-expression)

But this doesn't compile. Even a more simple

```
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, &compare> queue;
```

won't compile, with compare being a binary function returning bool.

> (error: type/value mismatch at argument 3 in template parameter list for ‘template class std::priority_queue’; expected a type, got ‘compare’)

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have no closing paren on the `boost::bind` here - before the > on the queue template params.  Is that a typo in posted code or in what you tried to compile?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This could work:

```
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, 
    boost::function<bool(int,int)> >
```

Then pass in your bind expression to the queue's constructor.

P.S. you're getting those compilation errors because you're putting runtime-evaluated expressions where a typename or constant expression are expected.

Comment: +1, This is a good solution.  I'll just note that unfortunately, this isn't exactly the same thing as statically supplying a specific template function/functor parameter, because `boost::function` uses dynamic allocation to create variable function objects.  So, you won't get the same kind of compiler-generated inlined efficiency that you would get with a custom, statically supplied function parameter.